# Pytorch Implementation

Tags: pytorch

How to see the actual implementation of PyTorch functionalities, classes, and methods.

I did not find them on PyTorch's official website. I want an easy way to navigate through the implementation to better understand the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this blogpost https://blog.christianperone.com/2018/03/pytorch-internal-architecture-tour/ quite insightful too

Answer (score 0):

1. Github will be messy but there you will find it.
   https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch
2. Check the subpages of https://pytorch.org/docs   and other pytorch packages.
   At most places you will find a `[SOURCE]` hyperlink on the page.
   For example at
   https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sequential.html#torch.nn.Sequential .
   That will lead you to the source code of the whole module:
   https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/container.html#Sequential